# How do I eliminate and prevent future stink bug infestations?

Tags: pest-control

Throughout the winter we tended to have 1-2 stink bugs buzzing around the house on any given day. We'd either vacuum them up or put them in the disposal. The humidity picked up for a bit and yesterday we had more like 12 or so buzzing around.

Is there anything we can do to control the critters? How could we figure out how they get in the house? Is there anything that can be done to make our house less attractive to them? Anything we can do to thin out their numbers or exterminate them completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this article [How to Control the Brown Marmorated Stink Bug](http://njaes.rutgers.edu/stinkbug/control.asp)

> Presently, there are no viable
> strategies for control of the Brown
> Marmorated Stink Bug. The use of
> insecticides has very short-lived
> effect and there is evidence of
> resistance development. Even where
> insecticide is effective, repopulation
> occurs through migration from
> non-treated areas. In addition,
> on-farm insecticide use is not ideal
> due to disruption of integrated pest
> management programs.
>
> **Homeowners**
>
> Do your best to prevent
> them from entering your home.
> Placement of screens over windows,
> doors and vents, removal of window air
> conditioners and caulking cracks in
> windows and doorframes will deter the
> adults from entering. Removal of
> window air conditioners is important,
> as numerous BMSB will enter this way.
> If small numbers occur indoors, they
> can be removed either by hand or by
> using a shop-vacuum.
>
> If large numbers are observed or have
> been observed in previous years, you
> may wish to contact your local pest
> control company who can do a perimeter
> pesticide spray. This must be done at
> the appropriate time (when the insects
> first appear) and control may be
> difficult to achieve. It is important
> to consider the effects of pesticides
> in your home before any pesticide
> applications occur.

It seems the best method of control is prevention, here is what the [Stink Bug Guide](http://www.stinkbugsguide.com/) has to say about controlling stink bugs...

> The easiest way to get rid of stink
> bugs is to never have them in the
> first place. Prevention is key to
> controlling stink bug infestations.
> Typically, they are attracted to light
> and heat reflected off of the house.
> Turning off the light at night during
> summer and fall nights can help reduce
> the number of stink bugs attracted to
> houses. Other methods of prevention
> include: sealing all windows and doors
> tightly, caulking any cracks and holes
> around the house, removing window air
> conditioning units, and treating the
> exterior of your house with chemical
> repellents.

Keep in mind that they lay their eggs on the underside of leaves. If you have any plants that you leave outside in the summer and bring inside in the winter, make sure you check the plants for eggs before bringing them into the house.

You can try contacting a professional exterminator, but from what I've read infestations typically reoccur.

As you may already know **Don't Squash them!** If you do you will quickly find out why they are called stink bugs!